# Zipping a directory recursively & skip container directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubyzip

Consider, we have following directory structure:

```
Location:
/Users/me/Desktop/directory_to_zip/
dir1 dir2 somefile.txt
```

now, If I use [rubyzip](https://github.com/rubyzip/rubyzip) to zip the contents of `directory_to_zip` using the following code:

```
directory = '/Users/me/Desktop/directory_to_zip/'
zipfile_name = '/Users/me/Desktop/recursive_directory.zip'

Zip::File.open(zipfile_name, Zip::File::CREATE) do |zipfile|
    Dir[File.join(directory, '**', '**')].each do |file|
      zipfile.add(file.sub(directory, ''), file)
    end
end
```

This will create a zip file named `recursive_directory.zip`, which will contain a container directory called `directory_to_zip` & inside `directory_to_zip`, will I find my files(`dir1 dir2 somefile.txt`)

HOw do I skip creation of `directory_to_zip` inside `recursive_directory.zip`, so that the zip file just contains the contents of `directory_to_zip` & not the directory itself.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Okay, I solved this on my own. If you are in same boat, here is here how I did it:

```rb
Zip::File.open(zipfile_name, Zip::File::CREATE) do |zipfile|
  Dir.chdir directory
  Dir.glob("**/*").reject {|fn| File.directory?(fn) }.each do |file|
    puts "Adding #{file}"
    zipfile.add(file.sub(directory + '/', ''), file)
  end
end
```

This works exactly I want. the limitation here here is that it doesn't handle empty directories. Hopefully, it would help someone.